# Add AppInsights support to WebApp or FunctionApp from azure-cli

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-cli

Is there a way to create and/or activate AppInsights for a WebApp or FunctionApp from the `azure-cli`?

Digging through the documentation now.

Answer (score 3):

I have also thought about your issue ago. To create an Application insight, it seems that the `az resource create` will be the only possible way currently as mentioned in the another answer. But I am not sure it 100% works, you could have a try.

To activate Application insight for a WebApp or FunctionApp, we just need to add a setting called `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` in the **Application settings** of  WebApp or FunctionApp. Just use the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
#retrive the InstrumentationKey of your application insight
$key = az resource show -g <resource group name> -n <appinsight name> --resource-type "Microsoft.Insights/components" --query properties.InstrumentationKey

#set the application insight for function app
az functionapp config appsettings set -g <resource group name> -n <function app name> --settings "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = $key"

#set the application insight for web app
az webapp config appsettings set -g <resource group name> -n <web app name> --settings "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = $key"
```

**Test sample**( the result of web app is the same):

[image]
**Check in the portal**:

[image]

Comment: If AppInsights key already in the function, the az functionapp config command fails. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently an open issue for creating an app insights resource via cli https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/5543

You can see the user is creating them like so currently

```
az resource create \
    --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --resource-type "Microsoft.Insights/components" \
    --name $NAMESPACE_PREFIX-appinsights \
    --location $PRIMARY_LOCATION \
    --properties '{"ApplicationId":"facerecognition","Application_Type":"other", "Flow_Type":"Redfield", "Request_Source":"IbizaAIExtension"}'
```

================================================================

According to the latest CLI documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/application-insights/monitor/app-insights?view=azure-cli-latest) , you can create a new App Insight resource by using the following

```
az monitor app-insights component create --app demoApp --location westus2 --kind web -g demoRg --application-type web
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly connection string for application insight can be fetched using Az cli

```
az resource show -g $RESOURCE_GROUP -n $APP_INSIGHTS --resource-type "microsoft.insights/components" --query properties.ConnectionString
```